# Does OkHttp's enqueue method implement AsyncTaskLoader?

Tags: android, okhttp, asynctaskloader

I am pretty new to android programming. I've written a code to perform API query using the OkHttp Library.

My question is, once the OkHttp's enqueue process has started, and the user immediately rotates the phone, thereby destroying and restarting the activity, does that cause a second enqueue process to occur, thereby causing the code to perform 2 OkHttp Api query in parallel?

I know that if we are using httpUrlConnections with AsyncTask (instead of OkHttp), this is a known issue. And we can bypass it by using an AsyncTaskLoader, which has a separate life cycle from our MainActivity. But I am just wondering of OkHttp also takes that into account.

Thank you! An example of my code is shown below if that helps in anyway.

```
private void performApiCall(String url) {
    mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // is network available?
    if (NetworkUtility.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
        // create new OkHttp client
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build(); // building the request
        Call call = client.newCall(request);


        // Asynchronous task
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                alertUserAboutError();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d(TAG, "OkHttp, onResponse received");
                // perform data download
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                    String jsonData = response.body().string(); // this is the raw data in json format
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                    try {
                        if (mMovieData == null) {
                            saveMovieData(jsonData);


                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mCurrentPage++;
                                    setRecyclerView();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "OkHttpCall completed");
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            appendMovieData(jsonData);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    mCurrentPage++;
                                    updateRecyclerView();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "OkHttpCall completed");
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                    alertUserAboutError();
                }

            }
        });
    } else {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        alertUserNetworkUnavailable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still use `AsyncTaskLoader` in your projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, once the OkHttp's enqueue process has started, and the user immediately rotates the phone, thereby destroying and restarting the activity, does that cause a second enqueue process to occur, thereby causing the code to perform 2 OkHttp Api query in parallel?

If your activity is automatically calling `enqueue()` when it is created, then yes.

> And we can bypass it by using an AsyncTaskLoader, which has a separate life cycle from our MainActivity.

Note that the Architecture Components' support for view-models and `LiveData` is Google's current direction for addressing the problems that loaders tried to address.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, and pointing out the view-model and live data.

Comment: What happens when `enqueue` returns after Activity has been rotated?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: If the `Activity` is directly using Retrofit, and it is using some anonymous inner class of `Callback`... that's not good. Ideally, your Retrofit call is not being done by something that has a lifecycle (activity or fragment), but is independent of those (e.g., repository).

Comment: @CommonsWare I just read your chapter in Android-Architechture book, where it explains well: `If you can work with the raw HTTP response, and it’s short, use the asynchronous API, as it saves you from having to fuss with your own thread. If the response requires significant post-retrieval work, use your own background thread and use the synchronous API`